# how to save graphic in pdf without showing it in a div? -Google chart

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization, jspdf

I am making a graph with google chart, which displays me perfectly, what I want is to send it to save in pdf. I found a library that converts the image of the graph and later use the library that converts it into pdf, which it does, but it saves the image according to the size that was assigned, I show 4 graphics in 4 boxes and when I send it to save in pdf it comes out of the problem as it is being shown in the `div`, my question is can a second function without showing it on the page and sending it directly to save the pdf with the desired size?

when saved it comes out of size,

```css
width: 400;
height: 200;
```

I want it to be saved with a size of

```css
width: 800;
height: 400;
```

this is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/tatoandry/pen/VweGNeX?editors=1010)

```js
google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ["Element", "Density", { role: "style" } ],
        ["Copper", 8.94, "#b87333"],
        ["Silver", 10.49, "silver"],
        ["Gold", 19.30, "gold"],
        ["Platinum", 21.45, "color: #e5e4e2"]
      ]);

      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      view.setColumns([0, 1,
                       { calc: "stringify",
                         sourceColumn: 1,
                         type: "string",
                         role: "annotation" },
                       2]);

      var options = {
        title: "Density of Precious Metals, in g/cm^3",
        width: 400,
        height: 200,
        bar: {groupWidth: "95%"},
        legend: { position: "none" },
      };
      var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(container);
  var btnSave = document.getElementById('save-pdf');
      google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    btnSave.disabled = false;
  });

  btnSave.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.addImage(chart.getImageURI(), 0, 0);
    doc.save('chart.pdf');
  }, false);
chart.draw(view, options);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="save-pdf" type="button" value="Save as PDF" disabled />
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: there are additional arguments you can add to the jsPDF `addImage` method, including height and width -- see [addImage](http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-addImage.html#~addImage)...